# Subset of the sequence space that's closed and bounded but not compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Consider the sequences space $l^1 = \{a = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \subset \mathbb{C}, \sum_{n = 0}^\infty|a_n|< \infty\}$ with the norm $||a||_1 = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty|a_n|$.

I want to show that the sequence $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \subset l^1$, given by $e_n(k) := \delta_{n, k} = \begin{cases}1&\text{if k = n}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ does *not* have a convergent subsequence.

Based on this, I want to construct a subset of the normed space $(l^1, ||.||_1)$ that is bounded and closed, but *not* compact.

Thanks in advance! I'm not very used to sequence spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subset consisting of the $e_n$'s. It's bounded, because each sequence has norm $1$. Since the distance between any two distinct sequences is $2$, any Cauchy sequence is constant and thus converges, so the subset is closed. However, it's not compact because, it does not have a convergent subsequence.

The reason your sequence doesn't have a convergent subsequence is that the distance between any two distinct terms of it is always $2$, and so no subsequence is Cauchy.